# Windows 10, cannot run any .exe from secondary drives

Tags: windows-10, permissions

When I try to run any exe from any secondary (non C:) drive or partition, I get a message box with `Windows cannot access the specified device, path or file. You, may not have the appropiate permissions for the item` if I try to run it from cmd I get `Access is denied.`.

Additional info:

- I'm administrator.
- I have full control over the files.
- Tried it with a known exe  (wordpad). Copied it on the Desktop and it worked. From anywhere on the secondary partition of the local HDD, or a removable USB didn't.
- This worked 3 months ago, not sure when it stopped working
- I'm the owner of the file

(edit: added that I'm the owner of the file)

Comment: Try taking ownership of the file and then try again.

Comment: Checked it. I'm already the owner of the file. Changed it and retook ownership just in case. (Added to the main post)

Comment: Tried both, neither works. Even tried making a symlink for the folder containing the file. Tired with symbolic softlinks since hardlinks cannot be created in between different partitions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was caused by a Local Group Policy Admistrative Template, `Local Computer Policy\Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Removable Storage Access\Removable Disks: Deny execute access`, which was manually set to enable.

After resetting it to `Not Configured` and rebooting the problem disappeared.

Apparently the secondary partition from my main hard drive was also considered a "Removable Disk".

Answer (score 6):

If the solution of [darmual](https://superuser.com/users/497660/darmual) did not cut it quite for me. The group policies did not change the registry entries needed to grant execute rights for removable media devices (for some reason my second hard drive was also considered a  removable device).

In order to gain write access to executable files in your "removable" media under windows 10 you should change the following register entries:

- HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Storage
- HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\RemovableStorageDevices{53f5630d-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}
- HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\RemovableStorageDevices{53f5630d-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}

> Deny_Execute

set it to **0**

[image: Registry entry example]

This solution worked for me and hopefully will fix your problem as well.

*Edit (14.05.2018):*

Here are the keys entries and their corresponding values. Save the lines of code into a .reg file and you will be able to change them all at once:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Storage]
"Deny_Execute"=dword:00000000


[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\RemovableStorageDevices\{53f5630d-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}]
"Deny_Execute"=dword:00000000


[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\RemovableStorageDevices\{53f5630d-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}]
"Deny_Execute"=dword:00000000
```

Comment: You specify the value for the third registry key, but not the first two. Could you add the values we should set the first two to please?

Comment: Hi, @Chris all the values are identical. You should set all to 0.

Comment: I didn't have the keys `HKLM\software\...\RemovableStorageDevices`. Still gave it a shot and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

After a very long research and lots of trial and error, I eventually managed to find the culprit.

It turned out to be the MultiPoint Connector Services additional feature.

Simply disable it under Control Panel > Programs and features > Turn Windows features on or off > MultiPoint Connector.

Answer (score 0):

None of these worked for me. However [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/df1f9145-a53d-49c0-856d-bbf26d835b46/cant-run-exe-files-from-external-usb-storage?forum=win10itprosecurity) someone suggests running from the command line, which is the best workaround I could find.

Open Command Prompt as Administrator (right click on the shortcut for the option), switch to the drive (type `D:`), cd to the directory (type `cd \path\to\dir`, and type `start filename.exe`

Answer (score 0):

None of this worked for me, what did was to back up the drive, format it, and restore the data. I also believe drives with BitLocker enabled can be problematic.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1099996)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, It turns out it was my firewall preventing the application from running. Maybe that will help you or anyone else stumbling upon this page.