# Suddenly unable to run any exe from usb drive on win10

Tags: windows-10, usb-flash-drive, group-policy, removable-media

I've been able to run executable from USB drives just fine on my work PC until about a week ago when I started getting

> Windows cannot access the specified device, path or file. You, may not have the appropiate permissions for the item

for everything. If I try to run it from cmd I get

> Access is denied

I tried different programs on different drives with the same result. Even had coworkers try on their machines and go the same, so it seems to be a group policy issue. Any advice on how I can get around the over zealous security?

I've already tried the solutions in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1247041/windows-10-cannot-run-any-exe-from-secondary-drives) question, none worked. 2/3 of the keys mentioned in the answer that talked about changing registry keys didn't exist and the 3rd was already 0, and the setting in the answer about the Local Group Policy Editor was already set to `Not configured`

**EDIT**

So apparently this is the result of a new group policy. Any ideas on how to circumevent that?

Comment: Maybe a work-wide av protection policy blocking usb devices just got rolled out? Have you contacted your work place IT department?

Comment: Not yet, i'm hoping to just go around it with asking. Last time I asked something sorta similar, the response was basically "oh yea well you shouldn't do that". They aren't very helpful

Comment: Also, i can still read/write to the usb just fine. It's just the exe's i can't run

Comment: Have you tried copying the contents of the USB locally and running it there?  In which case, do you get errors running unauthorized .exe files at all?  If you're using the executables for work, IT may be able to make it work for you.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage Yea that works, and so it's not an emergency, but i would really rather not do that long term. These crappy little laptops we get only have 256 gig SSDs so space is precious. And also it just pisses me off on principle that IT thinks we're all a bunch of bumbling half wits that need this level of hand holding (if that's actually what's causing the issue).

Comment: If your workstation is not a mini-PC, you probably have a spare hard drive slot.  Turn off the PC, open it up, see if there's an open slot, see if there's an open SATA port and available power plug.  A new 4 TB HD costs less than $80.  If you need the space for work, then IT is obligated to help you.  Offer to buy the HD yourself (I assume you bought your own thumb drive before).  Another solution is for IT to provide you with some file server storage space you can offload some of your other files to.  Again, for work activities, IT is obligated to help you.

Comment: Try this when booting in Safe mode, to see if the antivirus is the problem.

Comment: OK so I got with local help desk, and apparently there is some new group policy, they didn't even know about it.